# How many different choices of ofﬁcers are possible if F will serve only if he is president

Tags: combinatorics

I know it is a possible duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131211/combinations-of-officers),but i want my own approach.

### Question

> A president, treasurer, and secretary, all different,
> are to be chosen from a club consisting of $10$ people. How many different choices of ofﬁcers are possible if **F** will serve only if he is president?

#### My Approach

> Different choices of ofﬁcers possible=include **F** +Exclude **F**

$$=3!(\binom{9}{2}+\binom{9}{3})$$
$$=3*2(9*4+12*7)=720$$ which is incorrect.

Please help me out

Comment: If you select the treasurer and secretary FIRST, there are 9*8 ways of choosing these two slots.  Then (no matter what was selected for T and S), there are 8 possible selections for the president (7 left plus F) = 9*8*8= 576.

Comment: @AndrewGray That should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include $F$, then there are only $2!$ ways to organise any triple you've chosen for the board, not $3!$. Therefore it should be
$$
2!\binom92 + 3!\binom93 = 576
$$